# How to get Monitoring data of Azure ARM Virtual Machine using .Net SDK

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-monitoring

How to get Monitoring data of Azure ARM Virtual Machine using .Net SDK.

I tried using Microsoft.Azure.Insights and I am getting following error

## Server Error in '/' Application.

```
        <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
        <br><br>

        <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access raw metric data with [Microsoft Azure Insights Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Insights) which includes a unified API to retrieve monitoring metrics and operational events for all of the Azure resources that are available in Azure Resource Manager. And you can refer to [MSDN Library - Microsoft.Azure.Insights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn802153.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I did the same, however I am receiving some unknown CloudException which is updated in question